# Comparing a NSMutableArray using block

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray

I have `NSMutableArray* names`, which contains NSStrings.  I want to sort the array with the `caseInsensitiveCompare` method.

This is the code I've written:

```
names= [names sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^ NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2)
            {
                return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare: obj2];
            }];
```

The problem is that `sortedArrayUsingComparator` returns a NSArray instead of a NSMutableArray, and I get a warning and problems at runtime with this code.
Is there is a way to cast the NSArray to a NSMutableArray? Or do I have to copy all of the elements? This last solution is expensive: could someone suggest a nice, low overhead solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the name of the function that you are using (`sortedArrayUsingComparator`) tells you that it is going to return an array and not a mutable array.   Use the mutableCopy method of NSArray to get a mutable copy.

```
names= [[names sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^ NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2)
       {
           return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare: obj2];
       } ] mutableCopy];
```

Or, easier to read / follow:

```
NSArray *namesArray = [names sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult (id obj1, id obj2) {
       return [obj1 caseInsensitiveCompare: obj2];
       }];
names = [namesArray mutableCopy];
```

Comment: You should really just use `-sortUsingComparator` to do an in-place sort.

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII, +1 but I would also say he should just use `-sortUsingSelector:` since his comparator is just using a simple, readily-available comparison method. `[names sortUsingSelector:@selector(caseInsensitiveCompare:)]`

Comment: I agree that this would be better! I got stuck answering the question that he asked instead of offering a better solution.   :)